# Relationship with God vs Fellowship with God, are they synonymous?

Tags: biblical-basis, terminology, relationships, spiritual-growth, fellowship

Are these synonymous? My question is based on the point of already being a Christian. I’m open to any ideas and eager to hear them. Please note, I’m not looking for definitions of these terms. I’ve read many from various sources, and they are so minute that it renders them nearly identical. I am asking if the idea of relationship and fellowship (with God) is the same? If not, what are the differences? Does exegesis of biblical ideas exists, and if so what is the term for it? Of course any Bible verses that detail the differences in meaning of these ideas would be extremely helpful. I don’t know enough about Greek to figure that out on my own. I’m not asking out of mere curiosity, I’m studying to learn about these things for my personal growth.

Comment: Fellowship is a specific kind of relationship. A relationship could be anything, but fellowship indicates a partnership, participation, and sharing. The various Biblical passages that use the concept of fellowship with God show in more detail what it means to be in partnership with God.

Comment: Curiousdanni, thank you for responding. I’m not really looking for a definition of the terms, but if there’s a Scriptural difference between them, or between the ideas they are conveying. I’ve read passages that talk about fellowship and relationship with God, but I don’t know if there is a difference between them not in how they are translated, but in the Greek. What I’m asking is if they are synonymous, either the terms or the ideas.

Comment: a related term to "fellowship" is "communion"

Comment: GratefulDisciple, thanks for responding. So is communion related or unrelated to “relationship”? Trying to tie or untie these two ideas (fellowship vs relationship), as the case may be.

Comment: Rachel, I agree with @curiousdannii that "fellowship" is a specific kind of "relationship".  "communion" is a technical theological term also used in [Catholic liturgy](https://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Missal/Text/MCFL.pdf) ("The grace of our Lord Jesus Christ, and the love of God, and the communion of the Holy Spirit be with you all.") which seems to be even more specific than "fellowship" as it refers to the intra-Trinitarian relationship which we as sons/daughters of God shares since we have the life of God within our soul.

Comment: GratefulDisciple, thank you and Curiousdannii, these are very insightful and gives me much to ponder!